# JQuery using each() as classic for each loop and not all at once

Tags: jquery, loops, foreach, each

I'm trying to loop through a set of div tags and fade them in and out one at a time.
So far, using the .each() operator, it does them all at once.
How do you use .each() as a more classic for each loop?

Here is my JQuery code snippet and currently it fade all the div tags in and out together not one by one.

```
$("document").ready(function() {   
// all div tags are hidden at start 

    $(".myclass").each(function (i) {
      var $div = $(this);
      showDiv($div);
      hideDiv($div);
});

function showDiv(theDiv)
{
      $(theDiv).fadeIn(4000);
}

function hideDiv(theDiv)
{
       $(theDiv).fadeOut(4000);
}     
});
```

thank you for considering the question,

Comment: What's a "classic for each loop"?  This has to do with the timeouts.  You're calling show, and then hide, there is no delay between.

Comment: >classic for each loop" I didn't know how better to say it. thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not about using `.each()` versus a plain `for` loop.  The problem is that the animations are handled via timeouts (managed by jQuery).  Calls to `.fadeIn()` and `.fadeOut()` return immediately, before the animations have taken place.

You could add some delay to each `fadeIn()`, or you could structure your code differently:

```
$("document").ready(function() {   
  var divs = $('.myclass'), i = 0;
  function reveal() {
    if (i === divs.length) return;
    divs.eq(i).fadeIn(4000, function() {
      divs.eq(i).fadeOut(4000, function() {
        i++;
        setTimeout(reveal, 0);
      });
    });
  }
  setTimeout(reveal, 0);
});
```

Comment: Very nice, thank you for showing the .eq() operator, and using it as an indexed array.  Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Use delay:

```
var delay = 0;
$(".myclass").each(function (i) {
    var $div = $(this);
    showDiv($div);
    hideDiv($div, delay);
    delay += 100;
});


function hideDiv(theDiv, delay)
{
    $(theDiv).fadeOut(4000).delay(delay);
}
```

Comment: thanks. I added .delay into the jQuery string too.  very handy. yes, I'm working on a more concise version like that.

Comment: No problem. So if you used my solution then might as well nominate this as answer so that others reading the question would read this answer first.

Answer (score 1):

Your `.each` function works as expected. What doesn't work as expected is the fact that Javascript is asynchronous in nature. It doesn't wait for `showDiv` to complete before calling `hideDiv` again. The calls then start to conflict with each other.

What you want to use instead is an interval which isn't actually a part of jQuery itself but build into Javascript.

Something like this:

```
function showHide(theDiv) {
     if( $(theDiv).is(":visible") ) {
          $(theDiv).fadeOut(4000);
     }
     else {
          $(theDiv).fadeIn(4000);
     }
}

setInterval( function() { showHide("#theDivsID") }, 4100 );
```

Comment: yes.  this nesting aspect of jQuery (and javascript), is making more sense in light of your asynchronous comment.  thank you.